# Sustained flight with Fallout 4 Power Armor Jetpack?

Tags: fallout-4

Fallout 4's Power Armor Jetpack is pretty nifty, but is limited to a short flight time and distance. Is there a good way to improve this?

I tried hotkeying some Nuka Cola Quantum and Mirelurk Egg Omelets and it seemed like I was able to get more hover time, but there seems to be a ceiling on how high you can fly in one jump. I also tried the Piezonucleic chest, the Kinetic Servos leg mods, and 2 points in the Action Boy perk, but those only affect recharge rate after you stop flying for a moment. The Agility stat says it increases action points in VATS, but does that also translate to action points used for flying (and sprinting)?

What are other ways I can improve the flight time and/or distance? Is sustained flight possible?

Given these constraints:

- no cheat codes or console commands
- no file mods or UGC
- I don't care if it uses up fusion cores. (The game seems to throw em at me faster than I can use 'em anyway)

Comment: Jet Fuel may help.  Also experiment with tapping the space bar, a quick tap seems to give a substantial boost when you are already in the air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers supplied were very helpful, but didn't state the best solution which, in the words of Charlie Sheen, is

**"Drugs."**

Agility points help flight and action points help duration.

Per all my testing the height appears to be capped. (At approx 20 meters; using very rough vertical measurement by setting POV in fixed position and using reference features on buildings, etc.)

The total ground you can cover, however, depends on thrust management.

I was able to fly from the big island in bottom right corner of map (the one you can occupy, forgot the name) to the shore (near the old refinery/dung farm which looks like shortest island-mainland distance).  It's been a while since I played FO4, so going from memory for now..

Here is how I get super long (but not high) flights with power armor jetpack:

- Max natural agility (perks + bobblehead)
- Agility paintjob on armor
- Food items that grant bonuses to AGI and AP (deathclaw steak, mole rat chunks, cooked softshell meat, and maybe a couple others, I think.)
- Drugs that grant bonuses to AGI and AP (usually carry x100 jetfuel and hotkey it.. constantly addicted to Jet :D )
- Maxed Perks that increase power armor efficiency and movement speed (Though I have not yet confirmed that this has any effect; just stating that I had these before even crafting the jetpack; need to test with different unbuffed char next)
- Hotkey Ultrajet (although Jet works pretty good too since you can quickly regain the "high" with hotkeys)
- Make a running jump, and use Jet as you are running or jumping.
- Focus on distance, not height. The trick is to **manage thrust carefully, tapping jump key only as needed**, NOT holding it down. This is sorta possible without jet, but much easier while time is slowed. If you run out of jet, take some more! (Yeah, you'll get addicted, but don't worry! Addiction is a joke in this game compared to the previous ones; 4 diff ways to cure it. Or get perk where you never get addicted to chems.)

Also note that `Jetpack + Quad-barrel Missile Launcher + Jet = Archangel of Death`

Comment: You take Jet to use your Jetpack.  Nice.

Answer (score 2):

First - every point spent on agi improves your AP and so the lenght of flight. For my charisma-int build this is a good point to start, already have spent three points and got about three additional meters flight-height for every point spent.

Second - legs of armor. They can be modified in different ways to inflict the amount of AP spent, I'm currently trying out options.

The idea is that maybe endurance inflicts the duration too, but I don't know yet.

Comment: If this works with endurance the effects could potentially be amazing. I'm currently sitting on 17 endurance during day time, and I'm able to run huge distances. We're talking Goodneighbor to Bunker Hill kind of distances on a single AP bar. Will test when I have the chance.

Comment: With 17 endurance I was still only able to stay airborne for a couple of seconds, so I doubt endurance affects drain-speed for jetpack.

Comment: Do you also have the sprinting perk (uses half action points or whatever)? Wonder if that has any affect, will try later..

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Yes I have rank 3 in the "Moving Target" perk.

Comment: Why do you keep saying "inflicts"? Do you mean "effects"?

Answer (score 1):

Even with mods that remove the AP usage of jetpacks, they don't fly forever.  They mostly go straight up, and only go forward at about the speed which you jog, and after about 10-15 seconds they will slowly begin to descend anyways.  You can't fly longer than about 20 seconds period.  Kinda lame.

Comment: Until someone comes along with a mod to stop the descent anyway...

Comment: The height does seem to be capped. You can get longer flights, and finer thrust control by slowing down time with Jet (preferably UltraJet). By using foods and drugs that buff agility and action points on top of my naturally maxed agility, AND by using jet (hotkeyed) I was able to make it from the big island (forgot name.. settlement island) to the shore with a single jump.

Answer (score 1):

For longer distance jumps, simply hold your weapon in your hand. If you have your weapon stowed away, the sprint jump start that you do turns into regular running speed when you start using the jetpack. But for some reason when you have a weapon out (I use my combat knife because it takes up less screen space, allowing me to see where I'm landing), you can continue to maintain the sprinting speed.

Just remember to 'hop' with the jetpack if you're going for long distance - don't hold down the jump button but instead tap it as if you were skipping a stone. Even if you want to go straight upwards the most efficient way is to tap it (although you need to tap much faster than if you were jumping horizontally).

Comment: Interesting.. I *always* have a weapon readied when patrolling the wasteland so didn't even think to try if that made a difference. :D Definitely agree that the hop trick is best way to cover horiz distance. Even with time-slowing drugs it is tricky to achieve better height with hopping, still seems that height is capped somehow (maybe hardcoded limit?) which is weird because I thought gravity affects you the same whether you are moving vertically or horizontally...